# Why can't I delete this from my tables that have relationships?

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Why can't I delete these items from my database, they only have one relationship each, and I'm detaching and deleting each respectively. I have 3 tables Vendor, Brand and Product. The error mentions the Products table but there are no relationships in the Vendor table to the Products table, the relationship is with the Brand table and it's a one to one relationship.

Table structure

```
Schema::create('vendors', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('brands', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->integer('vendor_id')->unsigned();;
            $table->foreign('vendor_id')->references('id')->on('vendors');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('code');
            $table->string('sku')->nullable();
            $table->text('description_spanish');
            $table->text('description_english');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('discount');
            $table->string('cif')->nullable();
            $table->string('color')->nullable();
            $table->string('color_ab')->nullable();
            $table->integer('brand_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('brands');
        });
```

Vendor Model and relationship

```
class Vendor extends Model
{
    protected $hidden = ['created_at','updated_at'];

    public function  brands(){
        return $this->hasMany(Brand::class);
    }
}
```

Brand Model and relationship

```
class Brand extends Model
{
    public function vendor() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Vendor::class);
    }
}
```

Product relationship with Brand

```
public function brand()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
    }
```

Vendor destroy function

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $vendor = Vendor::findOrFail($id);
        $vendor->brands()->delete();
        $vendor->delete();
        DB::commit();

    }
```

Brand destroy function

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $vendor = Brand::findOrFail($id);
        $vendor->vendors()->delete();
        $vendor->delete();
        DB::commit();
    }
```

Product destroy funcion

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $product->sizes()->detach();
        $product->tags()->detach();
        $product->fields()->detach();
        $product->countries()->detach();
        $this->removeProductImage($product);
        $product->exportationFactors()->delete();
        $product->delete();
        DB::commit();
    }
```

when I try to delete a Vendor I recieve this error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 
1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: 
a foreign key constraint fails (`sondel`.`products`, 
CONSTRAINT `products_brand_id_foreign`FOREIGN KEY (`brand_id`) 
REFERENCES `brands` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `brands` where 
`brands`.`vendor_id` = 2 and `brands`.`vendor_id` is not null)
```

and when I try to delete a Brand I have basically the same error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 
1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: 
a foreign key constraint fails (`sondel`.`brands`, CONSTRAINT
 `brands_vendor_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`vendor_id`) 
REFERENCES `vendors` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `vendors` 
where `vendors`.`id` = 2)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The first error message mentions a `products` table, which you haven't shown.

Comment: @Barmar I have added the product table information to the question

Comment: Why is `vendor` a FK in `brand`? That means a brand can only be sold by one vendor. This seems like it should be a many-to-many relationship, so you should have a junction table relating them.

Comment: The way you have it, before you delete a vendor you have to delete all the brands that it sells. And before you can delete a brand you have to delete all the products with that brand.

Comment: assuming you are using MYSQL, you cannot delete a record if has a relationship to another record of other table, unless you use "on delete cascade" when you define the table in the database, you can check what is the SQL is ran when Laravel creates those tables.

Answer (score 0):

Error on Vendor Delete is Because You are deleting Vendor's all Brands which are again related to Products So, without deleting their related products you can't delete them.
So, you have to delete products at first. Create a relation of Products on Brand Model

```
public function  products(){
    return $this->hasMany(Products::class);
}
```

Then on Vendor's destroy get its all brands loop through and delete all products.

```
DB::beginTransaction();
$vendor = Vendor::findOrFail($id);
$vendor->brands->each(function ($brand) {
    $brand->products->each(function ($product) {
         $product->sizes()->detach();
         $product->tags()->detach();
         $product->fields()->detach();
         $product->countries()->detach();
         $this->removeProductImage($product);
         $product->exportationFactors()->delete();
         $product->delete();
    });
});
$vendor->brands()->delete();
$vendor->delete();
DB::commit();
```

Same On Brand's delete get all its products and delete its products first.

```
DB::beginTransaction();
$brand = Brand::findOrFail($id);
$brand->products->each(function ($product) {
     $product->sizes()->detach();
     $product->tags()->detach();
     $product->fields()->detach();
     $product->countries()->detach();
     $this->removeProductImage($product);
     $product->exportationFactors()->delete();
     $product->delete();
});
$brand->delete();
DB::commit();
```

I would like to suggest you to use Eloquent's deleting event on all three models then you will not need to care about nested model's foreign key and you will get rid of code repitation. see: https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/eloquent#events