# Where is my mistake? Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm trying to delete brands and vendors from my database, they are related to each other and brand is related to a product, I'm deleting these relationships before doing the final delete (at least I think I am) and I'm getting this error and I'm not sure what I'm missing. Originally in the brand model there was no relationship to the product, the relationship was in the product model. I've added the relationship to the brand model with no luck, still the same result.

Table structure

```
Schema::create('vendors', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('brands', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->integer('vendor_id')->unsigned();;
            $table->foreign('vendor_id')->references('id')->on('vendors');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('code');
            $table->string('sku')->nullable();
            $table->text('description_spanish');
            $table->text('description_english');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('discount');
            $table->string('cif')->nullable();
            $table->string('color')->nullable();
            $table->string('color_ab')->nullable();
            $table->integer('brand_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('brands');
        });
```

Models and Relationships

```
class Vendor extends Model
{
    protected $hidden = ['created_at','updated_at'];

    public function  brands(){
        return $this->hasMany(Brand::class);
    }
}

class Brand extends Model
{
    public function vendor() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Vendor::class);
    }

    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }

}

class Product extends Products
{
    public function brand()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
        }
}
```

Destroy Functions in the Controllers

Vendor destroy function

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $vendor = Vendor::findOrFail($id);
        $vendor->brands()->delete();
        $vendor->delete();
        DB::commit();

    }
```

Brand destroy function

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $brand= Brand::findOrFail($id);
        $brand->vendor()->delete();
        $brand->products()->delete();
        $brand->delete();
        DB::commit();
    }
```

Product destroy funcion

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $product->sizes()->detach();
        $product->tags()->detach();
        $product->fields()->detach();
        $product->countries()->detach();
        $this->removeProductImage($product);
        $product->exportationFactors()->delete();
        $product->delete();
        DB::commit();
    }
```

when I try to delete a Vendor I recieve this error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update
 a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sondel`.`products`, CONSTRAINT 
`products_brand_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`brand_id`) REFERENCES `brands` 
(`id`)) (SQL: delete from `brands` where `brands`.`vendor_id` = 1 and 
`brands`.`vendor_id` is not null)
```

and when I try to delete a Brand I have basically the same error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update 
a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sondel`.`brands`, CONSTRAINT 
`brands_vendor_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`vendor_id`) REFERENCES `vendors` 
(`id`)) (SQL: delete from `vendors` where `vendors`.`id` = 1)
```

Comment: `$vendor->vendors()` selects all vendors. And delete tries to delete them. They cannot be deleted because you added a constraint.  You want to delete `vendor`, not `vendors`

Comment: @Ibu I edited for clarity so it might be different, is the `$vendor->vendors` inside the Brand destroy function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I delete this from my tables that have relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57895468/why-cant-i-delete-this-from-my-tables-that-have-relationships)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to always delete all child relationships when deleting a record, you can do it in the boot function of the model on the deleting method. Something like this:

Vendor Model

```php
class Vendor extends Model
{
    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        // when you are deleting a Vendor, also delete all related brands
        static::deleting(function($vendor){ 
            $vendor->brands->each(function($brand) {
                $brand->delete();
            });
        });
    }

    protected $hidden = ['created_at','updated_at'];

    public function  brands(){
        return $this->hasMany(Brand::class);
    }
}
```

Brand Model

```php
class Brand extends Model
{
    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        // when you are deleting a Brand, also delete all related products
        static::deleting(function($brand){ 
            $brand->products->each(function($product) {
                $product->delete();
            });
        });
    }

    public function vendor() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Vendor::class);
    }

    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

Product Model

```php
class Product extends Products
{
    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        // when you are deleting a Product, also delete/detach all you need
        static::deleting(function($product){ 
            /*
            $product->sizes()->detach();
            $product->tags()->detach();
            $product->fields()->detach();
            $product->countries()->detach();
            $product->exportationFactors->each(function($exportationFactor) {
                $exportationFactor->delete();
            });
            */
        });
    }

    public function brand()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
        }
}
```

Then in your controllers just delete the record corresponding to each controller.

Vendor destroy function

```php
public function destroy($id)
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    Vendor::findOrFail($id)->delete();
    DB::commit();

}
```

Brand destroy function

```php
public function destroy($id)
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    Brand::findOrFail($id)->delete();
    DB::commit();
}
```

Product destroy funcion

```php
public function destroy($id)
{
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
    DB::beginTransaction();
    $this->removeProductImage($product);
    $product->delete();
    DB::commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `onDelete('cascade')` on every `$table->foreign('<Column>')` you have.

Example:

```php
$table->foreign('vendor_id')->references('id')->on('vendors')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Then no need to delete all the children first, just delete the parent.

Comment: to all or just the ones related to brand, vendor, i don't have trouble deleting other things in my database only these  brands and vendors

Comment: when I try this I get the same error but instead its in reference to another table that is related to the Products table

Comment: the `->onDelete('cascade');` works but not exactly for what i want.  i want that if i delete a vendor then all the brands related and products get deleted too, but if i delete a brand the products related get deleted, but not the vendor. with the cascade everything deletes everything which only half works for me. i can't have a brand deleting a vendor

Answer (score 0):

The problems you are having is in the products table, There is 2 ways you can solve this problem:

**Solution 1:**

Just like Yovi's answer states, you could simply add `onDelete('cascade')` to your foreign key on your brands & products table.

brands table:

```
$table->foreign('vendor_id')->references('id')->on('vendors')->onDelete('cascade');
```

products table:

```
$table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('brands')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Then your controllers destroy method should look like this:
vendor destroy function:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $vendor = Vendor::findOrFail($id);
    $vendor->delete();

}
```

brands destroy method:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $brand= Brand::findOrFail($id);
    $brand->delete();
}
```

**Solution 2:**

If you want to delete your rows manually, you just have the wrong order set on your destroy methods. You must first delete the youngest child starting at products -> brands -> vendors. Your methods should look like this:

Vendor destroy function:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    $vendor = Vendor::findOrFail($id);

    foreach($vendor->brands() as $brand){
        $brand->products()->delete();
    }

    $vendor->brands()->delete();
    $vendor->delete();
    DB::commit();
}
```

Brand destroy function:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    $brand= Brand::findOrFail($id);
    $brand->products()->delete();
    $brand->delete();
    DB::commit();
}
```

Overall I find solution 1 to be a lot cleaner.

Comment: my issue with the first solution is that i dont want the brand to be able to delete a vendor, when i use onDelete cascade everything can delete everything as in vendor deletes brands and products related with is good, thats what i want, but brand should only be able to delete products related not the vendor also. in the second solution im having issues where since i call the relationship to product now it calls all product relationships also inside the error first it was products table now its country_product which im not sure why is getting in the way of this brand delete

Comment: `onDelete('cascade');` should not delete a vendor when deleting a brand, I think maybe something else is wrong with the code, are you testing this using your original destroy brand method? If so, this method is specifically deleting your vendor in this line: `$brand->vendor()->delete();`